# How to get rid of control characters in perl.. specifically [gs]?

Tags: perl

my code is as follows

```
my $string = $cells[71];
print $string;
```

this prints the string but where spaces should be there is a box with `01 10` in it. I opened it in Notepad++ and the box turned into a black `GS` (which i am assuming is group separator).

I looked online and it said to use:

```
s/[^[:print:]]+//g
```

but when i set the string to:

```
my $string =~s/[^[:print:]]+//g
```

and I run the program i get:

```
4294967295
```

How do i resolve this?

I did what HOBBS said and it worked... thanks :)

Is there anyway I could print an enter where each of these characters are ( the box with 1001)?

Comment: Show us what the contents of `$cells[71]` are, please.

Comment: Did you write `my $string = ~` instead of `my $string =~` ?

Comment: Is there anyway I could print an enter where each of these characters are ( the box with 1001)?

Comment: -1 for not posting the code you actually ran.

Comment: @ikegami: So, per typical SO practices, he could correct his post and you'd remove the -1?

Comment: `while ($string =~ /[^[:print:]]/g) { say $-[0]; }` See `@-` in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: @Jonathan M, I had tried to rewrite, but couldn't figure how to rewrite without removing the question. And how does removing the -1 help induce the OP do the right thing next time?

Comment: @ikegami: What I'm saying is, tell him to correct, then reward him for doing so by removing.

Comment: @Jonathan M, oh, I misread. For sure.

Comment: `GS` is ASCII character 0x1D (Control-]); Unicode calls it "INFORMATION SEPARATOR THREE".  But the "box with `01 10` in it" implies 0x0110, Unicode "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D BAR".  Later, you say the box has 1001, which would be Unicode "MYANMAR LETTER KHA".  In short, you've given us no real idea what's actually in the string.

Answer (score 3):

When doing a regex match, you need to be careful to write `$var =~ /pattern/`, not `$var = ~ /pattern/`. When you use the second one, you're doing `/pattern/`, which is a regex match against `$_`, returning a number in scalar context. Then you do `~`, which takes the bitwise inverse of that number, then (`$var =`) you assign that result to `$var`. Not what you wanted at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the variable first, then do the substitution:

```
my $string = $cells[71];
$string =~ s/[^[:print:]]+//g;
```

Comment: Thats what I had... sorry i didn't specify

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP kind of indicated this mistake by putting the `my` keyword before the variable in the substitution.

Comment: @Jonathan M, it wasn't me, but probably cause it still doesn't explain why the OP got 4294967295.

Comment: @ikegami: Presumably it's printing 4294967295 because some code the OP didn't show us stores that in `$cells[7]`, but with some funny character where the spaces (what spaces?) should be.  The fact that 4294967295 is exactly 0xFFFFFFFF is probably not a coincidence.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, You're saying the OP wasn't using `my $string` as a defense to a post that tells the OP not to use `my $string`. (btw, see hobbs comment for the reason.)

Comment: @ikegami: Correction: `$cells[71]`, not `$cells[7]`.

Comment: @ikegami: Oh, right, he's applying `~` (bitwise negation) to the result of the `s///` operator.